# Jquery Ignore Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have this markup:

```
<span href="">Text <a href="">Link</a></span>
```

We have events bound to both elements. How do I make it such that when I click on the anchor tag, the event on the parent will not be triggered? I've tried using the Jquery method [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) but still no luck. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How are you using stopPropagation()? Something like this should work:

```
$("a.something").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.location.href = '/your/destionation.html';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why `stopPropagation()` isn't working for you. Given your HTML example, the following code functions properly, as the event on the `span` is not fired.

```
$('span').click(function() {
    alert('span');
});

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('a');
});
```

If you're using `live()` to bind your event handlers, then you'll have issues.

Comment: I tried using it the same way, and maybe I should tried again. BTW, there's an "e.preventDefault()" line, I'm not sure if this has something to do with the problem, well does it? Thanks.

Comment: @HealthWarning - Are you using `live()` to bind the events? `e.preventDefault()` disables the default behavior of the element. For example, if you didn't want to follow the `href` in the `a` element, you would use it to disable the behavior of the `a`.